# ChatterBot throws error when creating bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, artificial-intelligence, chatterbot

I am working on a ChatterBot project in Python, and I am encountering an error during training. The error message is as follows:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data] C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data] Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data] date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data] C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data] Package punkt is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data] C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data] Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\bot].py", line 12, in <module>
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 138, in train
for corpus, categories, file_path in load_corpus(*data_file_paths):
File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 63, in load_corpus
corpus_data = read_corpus(file_path)
File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 38, in read_corpus
return yaml.load(data_file)
TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

I am using the ChatterBot library, and the code I am running is as follows:

`````py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import yaml
import time

chatbot = ChatBot('phil')
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
              "chatterbot.corpus.english.conversations")

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        bot_response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
        print(f"MyChatBot: {bot_response}")
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
````      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for srsly
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis srsly
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, srsly, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Chatterbot is installed as 1.2.0 as it threw errors when i tried to upgrade:
`````

I would like my code to be a chatbot console, and the chatbot could access a database from a public training database. Please could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs, it looks like you are using `python 3.12`

Document says that chatterbot only support till `python 3.8`

[image]

You need to install `python 3.8` separately to work on chatterbot.

https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/